# Error in theme after upgrading to 2.2.5

Tags: magento-2.2.5

After upgrading to Magento 2.2.5 I am receiving the following error message, but only when my theme has the Luma theme as the parent - it works OK with the Blank theme.

```
Processing file '/var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Customer/web/images/icn_checkout.png'  for area 'frontend', theme 'Magento/luma', locale 'default'module 'Magento_Customer'
#0 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(73): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/framework/App/View/Asset/Publisher.php(61): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publishAsset(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#2 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticFile.php(89): Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\Publisher->publish(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File))
#3 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(189): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticFile->deployFile('images/icn_chec...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(136): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->processFile(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\PackageFile), Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#5 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(107): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deployEmulated(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array, false)
#6 [internal function]: Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->Magento\Deploy\Service\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php(186): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployPackage.php(108): Magento\Framework\App\State->emulateAreaCode('frontend', Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(300): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployPackage->deploy(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package), Array)
#10 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(219): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->execute(Object(Magento\Deploy\Package\Package))
#11 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Process/Queue.php(162): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->assertAndExecute('frontend/emodel...', Array, Array)
#12 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Strategy/QuickDeploy.php(76): Magento\Deploy\Process\Queue->process()
#13 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Service/DeployStaticContent.php(109): Magento\Deploy\Strategy\QuickDeploy->deploy(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/mydomain/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php(140): Magento\Deploy\Service\DeployStaticContent->deploy(Array)
#15 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(241): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(843): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(104): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /var/www/html/mydomain/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /var/www/html/mydomain/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
21 {main}
```

I have installed all the 2.2.5 files again but it hasn't made any difference and the file that it is looking for is present on the server in the correct location.

Does anybody have any ideas how to resolve this?